behave ./src/features --tags="tagname" marking all non tag matched scenarios as skipped instead of ignoring
I have a project with below structure.
project
    src/features
        feature_1
        feature_2
        steps
        environment.py

Assume feature_1 have scenarios tagged with @smoke @only_on_release and feature_2 have scenarios tagged @regression. When I try to execute below command, behave ./src/features ---tags=@regression, all scenario's which are not tagged with @regression are marked as skipped and @regression tagged scenarios are executed. Here I expect non matching tagged scenarios should be ignored, but its marking as skipped in console and also in behave-html-pretty-report. As per official docs, --tags will execute only matching scenarios. But in reality, its marking non-matching scenarios as skipped. Any idea on this?

UPDATE:
This is solved by passing --no-skipped arg along with same command.
behave ./src/features ---tags=@regression --no-skipped
